# CCS Selector for Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation

When selecting a field which contains a drop-down list with two options, I was able to find the xpath, but I would like to know if there is another method that I can use for this case

these are the the two elements:

ESS
Admin

```html
<div class="oxd-select-text-input" tabindex="0" data-v-5df604d8="">Admin</div>
              
<div class="oxd-select-text-input" tabindex="0" data-v-5df604d8="">ESS</div>
```

I need to get to that element

This is an xpath I tried but in cypress, but it doesn't work

```js
//\*\[@id="app"\]/div\[1\]/div\[2\]/div\[2\]/div/div/form/div\[1\]/div/div\[1\]/div/div\[2\]/div/div/div\[1\]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you would want to select the element by text inside, since the elements look the same.

Something like this:

```js
cy.get('div.oxd-select-text-input:contains("Admin")')
// or
cy.get('div.oxd-select-text-input')    // <- here is a list of two elements
  .contains('Admin')

//and

cy.get('div.oxd-select-text-input:contains("ES")')
// or
cy.get('div.oxd-select-text-input')    // <- here is a list of two elements
  .contains('ES')
```

Second best way is to specify the position in the list

```js
cy.get('div.oxd-select-text-input')    // <- here is a list of two elements
  .eq(0)                               // <- take first one
//or
cy.get('div.oxd-select-text-input')    // <- here is a list of two elements  
  .eq(1)                               // <- take second one
```

Comment: Thank so much Dzghig, but it doesn´t work !!!   appears :Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find content: 'Admin' within the element: <div.oxd-select-text-input> but never did

Comment: Sadly, this is working with the HTML you have given. Could you improve your question in some way that shows why it does not work?